# Most efficient way of parsing HTML header tags order

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to determine if a given page doesn't respect the header tags (h1,h2,etc.) order. As a matter of fact, I want to be able to parse a bunch of pages and that it returns me each page that **DONT** follow the headers order.

My firs goal was to be able to find out if an  is immediately followed by something else than an h2. Which I achieved with the following pattern

```
(?<=<h1[^<>]*>.+?)(?<!<h1[^<>]*>.+?<h2[^<>]*>.+?)<h[3-6][^<>]*>
```

The previous regex is working for me, although it is not really efficient and far from perfect.

So in **first place** i'd like to have some help improving this pattern and if possible an explanation comparing my old pattern and why it is so inefficient. And **in second**, I'd like to upgrade/modify the pattern to achieve the original goal which is make sure the document header tags order is respected.

**NOTE:**
I'm using RegexHero for benchmarking

[I know Regular Expressions are typically not best practice for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572) but this is more an exercise for myself to user more efficiently lookarounds, atomic grouping and such, thank you for your understanding.

We could use following pattern and following text as sample

**Pattern:**

```
 (?<=lol1.+?)(?<!lol1.+?lol2.+?)lol[3-6]
```

**Text:**

> lol1 bla lol3 bla lol2 bla lol4

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I've seen someone try to parse html or xml with Regex...

Comment: Hm, could you edit the title to make it HTML-agnostic?

Comment: @bergi if you think its appropriate, please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is extract your header sequence to an array that you could then manipulate. For example:

```
<h1><h3></h3></h1><h2><h3><h4></h4></h3></h2>
```

Would translate into:

```
[1,3,-3,-1,2,3,4,-4,-3,-2]
```

You could then use simple operations to validate your structure (for example the jump from one  value to the next is +/-1).

The regex:

```
/(<h\d|<\/h\d)/g
```

Comment: your answer is indeed valid, but it defeats the purpose true purpose of my question which is to get a better hang of lookarounds and grouping